# Calculating average of vectors using wildcard

Tags: r, vector, wildcard

I have a bunch of vectors (all with the same length) and want to make a new vector with the average value of some of the other vectors.
For the sake of simplification lets assume I only have 5 vectors (in my dataset there are a lot more). The names of the vector are counting, so the first vector is v_1, the second v_2, and so on. And what I want to do is to make the average of the first 4 vectors (the 5th should not be included in the average)

```
v_1    v_2    v_3    v_4    v_5
1       3      2      1      6
4       2      4      4      1 
2       4      5      5      2
...    ...    ...    ...     ...
```

What I would so is:

```
v_avg <- (v_1+v_2+v_3+v_4)/4
```

I assume there must be a nicer way to do this, where I do not have to write everything out but instead use some sort of wildcard? I tried something with grep(), but this only seems to work within a vector.

Any help would be really appreciated and thank you in advance!

Comment: Are your vectors contained in an object (e.g. `list` or `data.frame`), or just loosely scattered in your environment (I'm guessing the latter)?

Comment: You guessed right. They are just loosely scattered in the environment.

Comment: If they have the same length, consider an array object(matrix, data frame..) If it is a data frame you can try `keep <- 1:4; mean(colMeans(df[keep]))`. Or with a matrix `mean(mat[,keep])`

Comment: get them into a matrix by using something like: `sapply(ls()[grep("v_[0-9]+",ls())], get)` then you can subset out v_5 and use the solution from @PierreLafortune

Comment: Do you want the mean of the combined vector c(v1,v2,v3,v4), or the mean of 'rows'? (Because you divide by 4 in your example, and there are 12 values visible).

Comment: I want to have the mean of 'rows'. So to say I want to have a vector (same length as the other 4 vectors) that yields me for the first element, the average of the first elements of my 4 vectors.
The first element of my v_avg should be (1+3+2+1)/4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution: generate the variable names, turn them to symbols, build a data.frame with it, and use `rowMeans`.

```
rowMeans(data.frame(sapply(paste0("v_",1:4),as.name)))
```